# How could I make the bitmap image by using fromHdc method?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, gdi

I'd like to get the specific region by using way to get DesktopWindow handle like below code.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDCEx(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hrgn, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

    public void ScreenShot()
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
            IntPtr hdc = GetDCEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 1027);

            Point temp = new Point(40, 40);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(mPanel.Width, mPanel.Height, g);

            g.CopyFromScreen(PointToScreen(temp) , PointToScreen(PictureBox.Location) ,  PictureBox.Size);
```

}

This code actually works, but I'd like to get a copied image which is made from the process of CopyFromScreen. I have tried using code like Graphics.FromImage(bitmap), however I could not get the image that I wanted... I mean,, copied Image.
I could not find the way to get a Bitmap image when I use Graphics object fromHdc.
I have to use DC.... Is there any proper way??

Answer (score 2):

You are going the wrong way here, you don't need to get the desktop handle, CopyFromScreen will copy whatever is on screen now to the target graphics so you need to create graphics object from the image.
The following code create an 500x500 image of the top left of the screen.

```
public static void ScreenShot()
{
    var destBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500);
    using (var destGraph = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap))
    {
        destGraph.CopyFromScreen(new Point(), new Point(), destBitmap.Size);
    }
    destBitmap.Save(@"c:\bla.png");
}
```

and if you really have HDC you need to use BitBlt from gdi32:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although it is little bit late to gratitute(becoz Im lazy...) My problem has been completely cleared.

Comment: Did my answer helped or you solved it in other way? (close the question if it did)